# Find the generator matrix (block code) given the codewords

Tags: matrices, cryptography, coding-theory

So I was given the following (6,3) block code with some unknown values marked with x:

format: index,(msg) -> (code word)

1 (0 0 0)   ->  (0 0 0 0 0 0)

2 (1 0 0)   ->  (0 1 1 1 0 0)

3 (0 1 0)   ->  (1 1 1 0 1 0)

4 (1 1 0)   ->  (1 0 0 1 1 0)

5 (0 0 1)   ->  (1 1 0 0 0 1)

6 (1 0 1)   ->  (1 0 1 1 0 1)

7 (0 1 1)   ->  (0 0 0 0 1 1)

8 (1 1 1)   ->  (x x x 1 1 1)

The goal is to find the generator matrix.
My first idea is to take the vectors of code words 2, 3 and 5 and form the generator matrix.

$G = \left[ \begin{array}{rrr} 
0&1&1&1&0&0 \\\ 
1&1&1&0&1&0 \\\ 
1&1&0&0&0&1 
\end{array} \right]$

Now to check if this is correct, I would calculate the code words for (1 1 0), (1 0 1), (0 1 1) and find the missing bits for code word (1 1 1).

(1 1 0) * G = (1 0 0 1 1 0)

(1 0 1) * G = (1 0 1 1 0 1)

and (0 1 1) * G = (0 0 1 0 1 1), but according to the table, this is not the right code word. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Either the code is linear, or the given encoding #7 is incorrect (a copy/paste error happens easily) because the encoded version of $011$ is not the bitwise XOR of the encoded versions of $010$ and $011$. Your idea of using #2, #3 and #5 is works if the code is linear.

Comment: ^ NON-LINEAR :-)